# PHP API sending POST requests

Tags: php

I have this function that connects to an external API:

```
function ICUK_Request($url, $method = 'GET', $body = NULL) {
        $client = new IcukApiClient();
        $client->username = "user";
        $client->key = "pass";
        $client->encryption = "SHA-512";

        $req = new IcukApiRequest();
        $req->url = $url;
        $req->method = $method;

        if(!is_null($body)) {
            $req->body = $body;
        }

        $res = $client->send($req);
        if ($res->success) {
            $obj = json_decode($res->response);
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception('There was an error contacting the API.');
        }

        return $obj;
    }
```

the API docs are telling me to send the POST request like this:

```
POST /domain/registration/new/
{
   "domain_name": "domain.co.uk",
   "hosting_type": "NONE",
   "registration_length": 1,
   "auto_renew": false,
   "domain_lock": false,
   "whois_privacy": false,
   "contact_registrant_id": 1
}
```

so i tried this:

```
$arr = array(
    "domain_name" => "domain.co.uk",
   "hosting_type" => "NONE",
   "registration_length" => 1,
   "auto_renew" => false,
   "domain_lock" => false,
   "whois_privacy" => false,
   "contact_registrant_id" => 1
);

ICUK_Request("/domain/registration/new", "POST", $arr);
```

but thats giving me a response in the API Logs saying:

```
{
  "exception_message": "Internal API exception occured",
  "exception_type": "InternalApiException"
}
```

im not sure if this would be anything generic and if anyone can help on how to POST the data?

Comment: You're trying to send a php array, they are telling you to send your data as json. See http://www.json.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send it as json:

```
$values = json_encode($arr);
ICUK_Request("/domain/registration/new", "POST", $values);
```